# Does an accelerated spring change anything?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, work

> A block of mass M is attached with a spring of spring constant k. The whole
> arrangement is placed on a vehicle as shown in the figure. If the vehicle starts moving towards right with a constant acceleration a (there is no friction anywhere & vehicle is long),Then find maximum elongation in spring

[image: Here’s The Figure]

So what I did was
Let the elongation be $x$
Since the total acceleration of the block is $a$ so the total force on it should be $ma$

So $ma=kx$

Maximum elongation $x=ma/k$

But the actual answer is double of it. I can't understand why. It's probably because the spring is also accelerated, but can anyone explain how this works?

Comment: Why do you think the maximum is the same as the equilibrium? That would help with the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to having the mass hanging in a gravitational field $a$, and releasing it from $x=0$.

The equilibrium position has $ma = kx_{eq}$; however, when it gets to that position, it is moving. It has converted gravitational potential energy:

$$ U = max_{eq} = kx_{eq}^2 $$

into spring potential energy $\frac 1 2 kx_{eq}^2$, and has the remainder as kinetic energy. Hopefully you can see the factor of two.

Note that the Virial Theorem is in effect.